# Return the position of value from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to sum different columns of a data frame and return the position of the highest value.

Example1:
[image]

In this case, I would like to return the position with the highest column value of 4 that is 18:30.

Code used, to sum up, the columns, but how do I return the position of the highest value?

```
Sample code:

df_sum<-colSums(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Sample data:

```
df<- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), `16:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `16:10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `16:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `16:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `16:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `16:50` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `17:10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:40` = c(2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `17:50` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0), `18:10` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `18:20` = c(1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), `18:40` = c(1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0), `18:50` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(2, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0), `19:10` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19:20` = c(3, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `19:50` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `17:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `17:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `17:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `17:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `17:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `17:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Example2:

In this case, I would like to return the position with the highest column value of 3 that is 18:30, 19:00 and 19:20.

[image]

Sample data 2:

```
df2<-

structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), `16:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `16:10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `16:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `16:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `16:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `16:50` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `17:10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:40` = c(2, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `17:50` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0), `18:10` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `18:20` = c(1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), `18:40` = c(1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0), `18:50` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(2, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0), `19:10` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19:20` = c(3, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `19:50` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
        cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `16:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `16:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `16:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `16:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `16:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `16:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `17:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `17:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `17:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `17:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `17:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `17:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `18:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `18:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `18:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `18:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `18:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `18:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `19:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `19:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `19:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `19:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `19:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `19:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
        "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function :

```
return_col_max <- function(df) {
  tab <- colSums(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
  names(tab[tab == max(tab)])
}

return_col_max(df)
#[1] "18:30"

return_col_max(df2)
#[1] "18:30" "19:00" "19:20"
```

`-1` is to ignore the first column (`X1`) from the calculation.